# Vector with the same angle to 3 linearly independent other vectors

Tags: linear-algebra

How can I define the vector v that has the same angle to three other linearly independent vectors x, y and z? The vector v should be defined as a combination of the three other vectors.

Comment: 3D issue; I assume ?

Comment: @JeanMarie, three linearly independent vectors imply three non-coplanar vectors i.e. 3D.

Comment: @SarGe The "I assume" was a manner to say that it could have been said in the question...

Comment: Actually it's obvious but you're right, OP should have mentioned it in the question. :-)

Comment: Could be in 17D as well...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let $V_k, \ k=1,2,3$ your vectors. Norm them to unity: $\|V_k\|=1$.

Consider the two following planes passing through the origin :

- ($p_1$) with normal vector the difference $V_2-V_3$ : this plane is such that the orthogonal symmetry with respect to ($p_1$) exchanges $V_2$ and $V_3$ : therefore any vector of ($p_1$) makes the same angle with $V_2$ and $V_3$.
- ($p_2$) with normal vector $V_3-V_1$  (similar remark as before)

The intersection of these planes gives the direction of a vector $V$ such that

angle$(V,V_1)$=angle$(V,V_2)$=angle$(V,V_3)$.

In fact $V$ can be directly obtained by plainly taking cross-product of normal vectors:

$$V=(V_2-V_3) \times (V_3-V_1)$$

By expansion, we obtain the nice-looking formula:

$$V = (V_1 \times V_2) + (V_2 \times V_3) + (V_3 \times V_1)\tag{1}$$

(see remark dealing with **dual bases** at the bottom of this answer).

An example:

$$v_1=(0,3,4), v_2=(3,0,4), v_3=(3,4,0)$$

Once normalized (divided by their norms), they become:

$$V_1=(0,0.6,0.8), V_2=(0.6,0,0.8), V_3=(0.6,0.8,0)$$

Using (1), we obtain :

$$V=(0.48,0.48,-0.36)+(-0.64,0.48, 0.48)+(0.64,-0.48,0.36)=(0.48,0.48,0.48)$$

Let us check: the dot products of $V$ with normalized vectors $V_k$ are the same : $0.48*0+0.48*0.6+0.48*0.8= 0.672$. It is enough for being able to conclude. Indeed

$$V.V_k=\|V\|\|V_k\| \cos(\theta)=\|V\|\cos(\theta)$$
Having the same dot product (with normalized vectors, even with an un-normalized vector $V$) is actually the same as having the same angle.

**Remark about (1)**: take a look at a [similar question](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/2430529), asked in a particular case. The answer by @achille hui mentions a natural framework for understanding, at the cost of a certain abstraction ("dual bases"), how one can access directly to formula (1).

Comment: I tried to determine the cross-product of the two planes normal vectors. However I didn't get a good answer, can you explain how I can norm the vectors to unity and correctly determine the normal vector.

Comment: I am going to give an example as an Edit to my answer.